# cannot open file '%f' webstorm

Tags: initialization, webstorm

Hi Recently I installed webstorm in my linux mint 15 mate fresh install , but whenever I try to open Phpwebstorm from the menu it says in cannot find file '%f' .
And also it isn't initializing the ide , it directly goes to this error. But while running from the bin/.webstorm.sh it works fine, perfect initialization no error .
Here is the screenshot of the error.
[image: error screenshot]

is this a bug or my set up screwed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I have no idea why it was showing that message. But upon research,, I found in the menu properties there is the extra "%f" at the end. Remove that, voila. It works with no annoying error.